# Need to securely store and transmit Keys

Tags: android, security, android-intent, android-contentprovider, persistent-storage

The issue I am facing is an interesting one and my knowledge of security is strong, but my understanding is weak. That is, I understand the theory, but have had little practical application in this particular regard. I have stored passwords, transmitted them using salt, verified them a hash, etc. My needs here are similar but specific.

I have one application that other external application may "hook" into via a ContentProvider URI. External applications may be developed by anyone, thus I do not have control over them. However, I want to limit some access to subscribers. To facilitate this, each "subscribed" application will have a key registered to its package name. The ContentProvider then needs to verify this key as valid.

My issue is this:
Since it is passed via URI, it is easily possible to intercept the key in transit. Additionally, my subscribers need a method by which they can store their own key without having to connect to a secure server. They cannot store the key as a literal within their app, of course, as this makes for easy vulnerability. I am trying to provide as much of a solution as possible without having to "trust" the security of these other applications.

So, how do we store a key in both my database and their external application, and allow them to send it to me for specifically verified queries? I think my issue in understanding how to do this is the aspect of persistent storage and how it affects the model. That is, with a password model, the password is typed and not typically stored.

FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the key in an encrypted challenge / response.

Client requests challenge value encrypted with a predetermined per application public key.
If the client then returns the correct value to the server encrypted using the client specific server's public key then the handshake was a success.

Using a per application private key / public key and something like a guid for challenge value, it would be very hard to duplicate.

and the keys never change hands except when registering the application developer initially.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a sample? I think that in this circumstance I have to see the storage and transmission, as I am not sure where my disconnect is...

Comment: Ack! God! I don't know why my brain was having soooo much trouble with that concept and how it developed that disconnect, but it is solved now! Thanks sooo much.